# Handled exception still being written to stdout

Tags: java, logging, jetty, stdout

I'm using jetty server for hosting my java app. I recently added request timeouts to kill requests that take too long. The file that logs my `stdout` (which normally should be empty) started to fill up with `InterruptedException` stack traces. Something like:

```
java.lang.InterruptedException
    ...... Some lower level code-lines of my project
    at com.mycompany.webapps.MyController.myMethod(MyController.java:252)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor67.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:920)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:816)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:801)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:738)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1651)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.UserAgentFilter.doFilter(UserAgentFilter.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1622)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:549)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1045)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536)
```

So, I added try-catch in `myMethod` (The highest method which is under my control):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myUrl/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> myMethod(final HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable final EncodedId id) {
  try {
    return serveImageRequest(request, sourceId.getId(), docId.getId(), dimensions.getWidth(), dimensions.getHeight());
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    log.error(ex.getMessage());
    return null;
  }
}
```

The `log` variable is a logger instance (using `log4j`) that writes the messages to a dedicated log file (and not the `stdout`). And still, messages are written to `stdout`. The only difference is that now they're also written to the log file. I can't find the reason for it to be written to `stdout` and I have to avoid it since the file that represents `stdout` does not have a rolling policy.

Comment: write lots or write less into it, a stdout file should still have a rolling policy

Comment: @guido - Perhaps but that's really not the issue here

Comment: ok that's why i posted a comment; you should post your log4j configuration and how you start jetty in order to have more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the root for the issue was in a 3rd party library which catches an exception and prints it stack trace to stdout. This is this was being printed although I caught and handled the exception.